# How to Get your manager with Javascript

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, user-profile

I want to get the user's manager using Javascript Client Object model.

How can I do this?

Comment: please give me a solution for 2010 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an instance of a manager object by using [PeopleManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj667813.aspx) class in JSOM SharePoint 2013.
See the sample code below:

```
//Make sure SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
var userProfileProperties;

function getUserProperties() {

    // get the target users domain name and account name.
    var targetUser = "SomeDomain\\SomeUserName";

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Specify the properties to retrieve
    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
            clientContext,
            targetUser,
            profilePropertyNames);

    // Get user profile properties for the target user using the UserProfilePropertyFor method.
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    // Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
    var messageText = "\"PreferredName\" property is "
        + userProfileProperties[0];
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
        + userProfileProperties[1];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

In SharePoint 2010 and 2007, you can use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices) library.

Comment: Great Thanks a lot. But i guess it's only for Sharepoint 2013? Do we have a solution for Sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to directly query the User Profile Service through JavaScript in SharePoint 2010. You can use SPService though

Comment: You can create a SOAP request and use the UserProfileService.asmx web service.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit @MatthewMcDermott

Comment: i Have tried this http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/29/capturing-the-current-users-manager-in-moss-using-spservices-and-getuserprofilebyname/ but getting an exception "Internal Server error" on google chrome console window

Comment: Which SP version are you using? Foundation or Server? Could you paste the code?

Comment: Version is Sharepoint 2010 Server not foundation

Answer (score 1):

```
var managerName;
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
    async: false,
    AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Manager')").each(function() {
        managerName = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
        alert(managerName );
      });
    }
  });
```

The Above is the code used.

I want manger in alert. Version of the sharepoint Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 not foundation.

@Falak Mahmood. Please help. I am getting this exception in google chrome

> POST url/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 send jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 p.extend.ajax
>   jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 Q.fn.SPServices
>   jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js:19 (anonymous function) made.js:25 k
>   jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 l.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 p.extend.ready
>   jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 D

Comment: I know this post is old, but I just tried this code in Firefox and Chrome and it worked fine. There must be something else going on.

Comment: worked for me like charm.. thanx.. was struggling alot

Comment: I need to get the Id of the manager in the same way... Is it possible?